# Zorin OS boots into emergency mode

Tags: boot, zorin

I have been using Zorin OS 15.2 for over 2 weeks. It's been working fine without any problems at all until today when I switched on my laptop it booted into emergency mode.
The `journalctl -xb` command gave me this log:

http://dpaste.com/124GQE7

I have pretty much no idea what went wrong, I don't remember doing anything that would have caused my OS to boot into emergency mode.

Things I have tried to fix this:

1. Used a live USB, in the terminal I ran a `fsck` check on my Zorin OS partition, it showed there was some error but it fixed it anyway. When I tried booting after this it still loads into emergency mode.
2. I was having certain PCIe Bus errors shown in the log files. It was written:

> FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so I disable it

I tried the solutions given in this site:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190522143232/https://forum.antergos.com/topic/10904/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected-type-physical-layer

where I disabled the ASPM by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file into this:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"`

And yet the problem still persists as it still boots into emergency mode.

NOTE: The log text in the pastebin url that I have given above is after I booted into emergency mode after setting the `pcie_aspm` to off as I said above.

Please help me out here as I don't know what to do next to have my OS running up again.

P.S: I went to recovery mode to run `fsck` check but for some reason, I was not able to go up or down and my keyboard inputs were not working or responded only after I kept pressing a key for a long time. That's why I created a live USB and did `fsck` check from there.

Laptop Info:

Acer Nitro 7

My OS was installed in partition: `/dev/nvme1n1p2`

I have dual booted my laptop with Windows in `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and another NTFS partition in `/dev/nvme0n1p2`

**UPDATE:**
When I went to `/etc/fstab`, this is what it showed:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/nvme1n1p2 :
UUID=4d12330f-df04-4be3-b2c9-f3a68210a70b   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/nvme1n1p1 :
#UUID=D4C7-8EDC /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0   1
#Entry for /dev/nvme0n1p2 :
UUID=3917C4AD3279A8CF   /media/atulu/3917C4AD3279A8CF   ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_IN  0   0
#Entry for /dev/nvme0n1p1 :
UUID=0B40D97D7E09A62B   /media/nvme0n1p1    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_IN   0   0
/swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0


UUID=D4C7-8EDC  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

but when I ran blkid, the output was:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="0B40D97D7E09A62B" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="windows" PARTUUID="30dc3ca6-e51f-43f5-ac5e-fd752f8ac23a"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="438F66FE45D6DE99" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="backup" PARTUUID="917c4a5c-e987-412f-a283-b88301a7b9fd"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="D4C7-8EDC" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="6f577372-59cf-4f56-b162-8d77b1c5a22c"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="4d12330f-df04-4be3-b2c9-f3a68210a70b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="234c9720-57e0-412b-9316-531054fbfd52"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ZORIN OS 15" UUID="C414-F2D2" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00141c12-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
```

I noticed that the UUID of my partition nvme0n1p2 is different in the above 2 outputs. I remembered that I had formatted this partition yesterday and stored some files in it. Could this be the reason why my OS is booting into emergency mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily got my OS working again.
Apparently a change in UUID in any partitions that is visible to the OS can lead to the OS booting into emergency mode.
All I had to do was:

- enter `blkid`
- Take note of all the UUIDs in every partition.
- And now enter `cat /etc/fstab`.
  In my case the UUID of partition "nvme0n1p2" was different from what it had showed in `blkid`.
- So, all I had to do was: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
- change the UUID of the partition to whatever UUID `blkid` showed.
- Now enter `reboot`

NOTE: The above method is for doing it from the emergency mode itself (after pressing enter). You can also use a live USB, mount the particular OS partition and do the same steps.

Check out this link for further reference:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/960790/stuck-in-emergency-mode-and-nothing-works

Comment: THANK YOU! This post was super helpful and saved my system!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :D